# tcp socket problem on android

Tags: android

I need to use the tcp socket connection to get the data from a bluebox, if I input a comment, such as "getcolor", the bluebox will send me the information like"red, blue".
In this case the bluebox as a server and I do not need to program on it, but I have problem to show the information on the EditText.

```
public class sender {
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{

        Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.176",14111);

        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

        BufferedReader msg = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));         
         PrintWriter ou = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out)),true);

         String buffer = new String("");
         String ms = "";
      while(true)
      {
          while(in.ready())

              buffer+= in.readLine()+ "\n";
          String[] line = buffer.split("\n");

          while(msg.ready())
              ms = msg.readLine();
          if(ms.equals("exit"))
          {
              break;
          }
          if(!ms.equals(""))
          {
              ou.println(ms);
              ou.flush();
              ms = "";
          }
          if(!buffer.equals(""))
          {

              System.out.print(buffer);
              buffer = "";

          }

      } 

      in.close();
      out.close();
      socket.close();

}
}
```

this java code works, but it fails in the android code below:

```
public class BlueBoxApp extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

Context appInstance = this;
private EditText info;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           info = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    try{

        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.176");//TCP服务器IP地址

            Log.d("TCP", "server,receiving...");

          Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr,14111);


           try {   


           OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
           BufferedReader msg = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));          
         PrintWriter ou = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out)),true);

            String buffer = new String("");
            String ms = "getsensorno";
            Log.d("TCP", "sending:'"+ms+"'");
        while(true)
        {
          while(in.ready())

              buffer+= in.readLine()+ "\n";

          while(msg.ready())
              ms = msg.readLine();
          if(ms.equals("exit"))
          {
              break;
          }
          if(!ms.equals(""))
          {
              ou.println(ms);
              ou.flush();
              ms = "";
          }
          if(!buffer.equals(""))
          {

             info.setText(buffer);
            buffer = "";

          } 
        } 

            } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "error",e);

        }finally{

            socket.close();

        }

        }catch(Exception e){

           Log.e("TCP", "error",e);

        }
}
}
```

what is the problem and how to set a thread for it? Thanks!

Comment: What is the exception? May be it cannot connect to internet from emulator?

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, as you indicated, is that you are doing the networking part on the main thread.

Setting a new thread is easy, consider using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Please read the documentation (which is very good) before jumping to implement it, it will make it much easier IMHO.

Also, make sure you have internet permission in your **AndroidManifest.xml**